# Setting edittext inside Recyclerveiw

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have an recyclerview contaning edittext and textview and i have a button outside recyclerview . I want to validate the edittext on click of button (edittext.setError("required")) , For that i have used addTextChangedListener and in onTextChanged() method stored charSequence in Hashmap .Below is my onBindViewHolder

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {



    String label = mData.get(position).getLabel();
    holder.label.setText(label);

    holder.label_input.setTag(position);

    holder.label_input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
          //  Log.w("ontextchanged","i = "+i+" i1 = "+i1+" i2 = "+i2+""+"char seq "+charSequence.toString()+"position = "+position);
            stringHashMap.put(""+position,""+charSequence);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });


}
```

and in activity on click of button fetched the stored value depending on position , Below is Activity button onclick

```
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        for (int i = 0; i< TimeSheetDetailAdapter.stringHashMap.size(); i++) {

            //Entered edittext value from hashmap
            String data = TimeSheetDetailAdapter.stringHashMap.get(""+i);


            }

    }
});
```

And i am getting the entered edittext value in data correctly depending on position , but the problem is i want to validate each edittext and if the data is empty , i want to set the particular edittext with edittext.setError("required") , For that i have tried

```
 if(recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i) instanceof TimeSheetDetailAdapter.ViewHolder){
                    TimeSheetDetailAdapter.ViewHolder childHolder = (TimeSheetDetailAdapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i);

                    childHolder.label_input.setError("required");
```

But it is setting error to only visible item in the screen i.e only if the edittext is visible it will set, the item which are invisible it wont set . i know the concept of recyclerview , i have tried with findViewHolderForAdapterPosition() also , but no help , please help me in sort out this , how can i access the views which are invisible and set eroor or any other way of doing it .

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up in a better solution

```
 if (data.equals("empty") || data.equals("")) {

                        isAllDataFilled = false;
                        //Scrolling to the respective position
                        linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(i, 0);

                        //giving delay of 200ms to get the view and then setting error for that
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                TimeSheetDetailAdapter.ViewHolder childHolder = (TimeSheetDetailAdapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i);
                                childHolder.label_input.setError("error");
                            }
                        }, 200);


                        enteredDataList.clear();
                        break;
                    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can make an arraylist of messages that you want to display on recycler list, by its position respectively.

and access that array list to set it in label. I think this might be only solution. Because you don't have any access to list items which are not visible.

Comment: Thank you for reply , i ll try it and post it back

Comment: . .Thank you , i tried , it is also one of the solution